# Trying to remove an item from a list using classes

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I am working on trying to implement a remove entry option for this address book program I am working on that uses object oriented programming. The issue I am running into though is when I try to remove an element from the list, it removes all the elements except for the last element.

I have tried creating a list and iterating through it inside the remove_entry function in the AddressBook class instead of trying to remove the element directly from the self.people list that I initialized in the init function of my Address Book class. This is similar to what I did the display_summaries function in the controller class, but it did not solve my problem. When I tried doing this, it did not remove any elements from the list.

```
# Imports
import pickle
import os.path

# Constants
SAVE_FILE_NAME = 'address_book_contents.pickle'
INSTRUCTIONS = '''Address Book Application
Press:
a to add an entry
r to remove an entry
d to display a list of all entries in summary form
s to display a list of all entries sorted alphabetically in summary form
i to print these instructions again
q to quit
'''
CONFIRM_QUIT_MESSAGE = 'Are you sure you want to quit (Y/n)? '
SUMMARY_TEMPLATE = "%s %s DOB: %s email: %s"

### Classes Section
class AddressBook (object):
    ''' 
    This class holds and manages a list of my contacts 
    '''

    def __init__ (self):
        ''' Set people attribute to an empty list '''
        self.people = []

    def add_entry (self, new_entry):
        ''' Adds a new entry to the list of people in the address
        book. The new_entry is an instance of the AddressEntry
        class'''
        #Adds the entry to people list
        self.people.append(new_entry)

    def remove_entry(self, entry):
        '''Removes an entry from the list of people in the address book.
        Entry is an index and comes from the remove_entry function in
        the Controller class '''
        try:
            entry = int(entry)
            #return self.people.remove(self.people[entry-1])

        except IndexError:
            #print("INVALID ENTRY! There is no entry in the address book for the number you entered")
            return "INVALID ENTRY! There is no entry in the address book for the number you entered"
        except ValueError:
            return "INVALID ENTRY! Please enter an integer number instead of a character"
        else:
            entry = int(entry)
            del self.people[entry-1]

    def is_list_empty (self):
        return self.people

    def save(self):
        with open(SAVE_FILE_NAME, 'wb') as file_object:
            pickle.dump(self, file_object)



class AddressEntry (object):
    '''
    This class has one instance for each person's details
    '''
    def __init__ (self, first_name=None, last_name=None, email=None, DOB=None):
        '''Initializes attributs f_name, l_name, email, and birthday.
        Each arg is a string.
        Birthday should be a string in the format MM DD, YYYY
        '''
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.email = email
        self.DOB = DOB

    #Function that overites default __repr__ so that print(person1) actually prints the values we passed into __init__
    def __repr__ (self):
        '''Given an AddressEntry object self return a readable string
        representation
        '''
        template = "AddressEntry(first_name = '%s', "+\
                "last_name = '%s', "+\
                "email = '%s', "+\
                "DOB = '%s')"

        attributes = (self.first_name, self.last_name, self.email, self.DOB)

        return template%attributes



class Controller(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.address_book = self.load()
        if self.address_book is None:
            self.address_book = AddressBook()

        self.run_interface()

    def load(self):
        if os.path.exists(SAVE_FILE_NAME) is True:
            with open(SAVE_FILE_NAME, 'rb') as file_object:
                address_book = pickle.load(file_object)
            return address_book
        else:
            return None

    def run_interface(self):

        print(INSTRUCTIONS)
        while True:
            command = input('What would you like to do? (press i to see all the options again) ')
            type(command)
            if command == 'a':
                self.add_entry()
            elif command == 'r':
                self.remove_entry()
            elif command == 'd':
                print("Displaying summaries of all people stored in the address book")
                self.display_summaries()
            elif command == 's':
                self.sort_entries()
            elif command == 'i':
                print(INSTRUCTIONS)
            elif command == 'q':
                user_quit = input(CONFIRM_QUIT_MESSAGE)
                type(user_quit)
                if user_quit == 'Y' or user_quit == 'y':
                    print('\nSaving...')
                    self.address_book.save()
                    print("\nThank you for using my address book application; come again soon!")
                    break
                elif user_quit == 'N' or user_quit == 'n':
                    continue
            else:
                print("I don't recognize that instruction (%s) "%command)

    def add_entry(self):
        print("Adding a new person to the address book")
        print("What is the person's: ")
        first_name = input("First Name? ")
        type(first_name)
        if first_name == 'q':
            print('Not Adding')
            return
        last_name = input("Last Name? ")
        type(last_name)
        if last_name == 'q':
            print('Not Adding')
            return
        email = input("Email Address? (if they don't have one, just enter None) ")
        type(email)
        if email == 'q':
            print('Not Adding')
            return
        DOB = input("Date of Birth? (Enter in the format MM DD, YYYY) ")
        type(DOB)
        if DOB == 'q':
            print('Not Adding')
            return

        new_entry = AddressEntry(first_name, last_name, email, DOB)
        self.address_book.add_entry(new_entry)
        values = (first_name, last_name)
        print("Added address entry for %s %s\n"%values)

    def display_summaries(self):
        '''for index, e in enumerate(self.address_book.people):
            values = (e.first_name, e.last_name, e.DOB, e.email)
            entry = SUMMARY_TEMPLATE%values
            print("%s: %s"%(index+1, entry))'''
        if self.address_book.is_list_empty() == []:
            print("Cannot display summaries because the address book is empty")
            return
        else:
            list1 = []
            for i in self.address_book.people:
                values = (i.first_name, i.last_name, i.DOB, i.email)
                list1.append(values)

            list1 = sorted(list1)

            for index, e in enumerate(list1):
                entry = SUMMARY_TEMPLATE%e
                print("%s: %s"%(index+1, entry))

    def remove_entry(self):
        print("Removing a person from the address book\n")
        if self.address_book.is_list_empty() == []:
            print("There are no entries to remove from the address book")
            return
        else:
            self.display_summaries()
            while True:
                user_input = input("\nEnter the number of the entry you would like to remove: ")
                type(user_input)
                if user_input == 'q':
                    print("Exiting remove entry")
                    return

                if self.address_book.remove_entry(user_input) == "INVALID ENTRY! There is no entry in the address book for the number you entered":
                    print(self.address_book.remove_entry(user_input))
                elif self.address_book.remove_entry(user_input) == "INVALID ENTRY! Please enter an integer number instead of a character":
                    print(self.address_book.remove_entry(user_input))
                else:
                    print("Entry number "+user_input+" has been removed")
                    break

    def sort_entries(self):
        print("Sorting Entries")
        if self.address_book.is_list_empty() == []:
            print("Cannot sort because the address book is empty")
            return
        else:
            list1 = []
            for i in self.address_book.people:
                values = (i.first_name, i.last_name, i.DOB, i.email)
                list1.append(values)

            list1 = sorted(list1)

            for index, e in enumerate(list1):
                entry = SUMMARY_TEMPLATE%e
                print("%s: %s"%(index+1, entry))



### Main section
controller = Controller()
```

This is the output I am getting when trying to remove just the first element from the list:

```
What would you like to do? (press i to see all the options again) r
Removing a person from the address book

1: Eric s DOB: 1 email: 1
2: Joe J DOB: 1 email: N
3: Joe S DOB:  email: 


Enter the number of the entry you would like to remove: 1
Entry number 1 has been removed

What would you like to do? (press i to see all the options again) d
Displaying summaries of all people stored in the address book
1: Joe S DOB:  email:
```

What I am expecting to get is:

```
Enter the number of the entry you would like to remove: 1
Entry number 1 has been removed

What would you like to do? (press i to see all the options again) d
Displaying summaries of all people stored in the address book
1: Joe J DOB: 1 email: N
2: Joe S DOB:  email:
```

Answer (score 0):

You main problem is in this little block:

```py
if self.address_book.remove_entry(user_input) == "INVALID ENTRY! There is no entry in the address book for the number you entered":
    print(self.address_book.remove_entry(user_input))
elif self.address_book.remove_entry(user_input) == "INVALID ENTRY! Please enter an integer number instead of a character":
    print(self.address_book.remove_entry(user_input))
else:
    print("Entry number "+user_input+" has been removed")
    break
```

In the `remove_entry` method of class `Controller`.

Notice that both in the `if` and `elif` you are **actually calling** the function each time with the expression `self.address_book.remove_entry(user_input)`. So what happens is in the first check of the `if` the first entry is removed, and then also in the check of the `elif` the second entry is removed!

What you want to do is call the remove function **once** and then perform the checks. Something like this:

```py
remove_result = self.address_book.remove_entry(user_input)

if remove_result == "INVALID ENTRY! There is no entry in the address book for the number you entered":
    print(remove_result)
elif remove_result == "INVALID ENTRY! Please enter an integer number instead of a character":
    print(remove_result)
else:
    print("Entry number "+user_input+" has been removed")
    break
```

Except from that your code has a few issues or just not well typed code. If you're a beginner I would suggest starting with simpler projects to get the hang of it.